# JavaScript function returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Can someone tell me why the returning vector from `TriangulosParaLinhas` doesn't save in vector Lines?

```
if (lineMode == true) {
       var lines = triangulosParaLinhas(vertices);
 }

function triangulosParaLinhas(vertices) {
  var pontos = [];
  for ( i = 0; i < vertices.length / 3; i = +3) {

    pontos.push(vertices[i]);  
    pontos.push(vertices[i + 1]);

    pontos.push(vertices[i + 1]);
    pontos.push(vertices[i + 2]);

    pontos.push(vertices[i + 2]);
    pontos.push(vertices[i]);
  }
  return pontos;
}
```

Comment: what is in `vertices` and what is the expected output

Comment: `lineMode` is `false`?

Comment: lineMode is true and dont save the vector pontos into lines

Comment: in vertices are the points group 3x3 but i want to group 2x2 because i have to draw in canvas with gl.LINES function

Comment: in this case is for a triangle with triangles inside, moving with a slider

Comment: when i call var lines = triangulosParaLinhas(vertices) why the return from the function dont save in lines?

Comment: Post an example array for `vertices` that you would pass to the `triangulosParaLinhas` function

Comment: var vertices = [
        vec2(-0.5, -0.5),
        vec2(0.5, -0.5),
        vec2(0, 0.5)
    ];

Comment: with the 3 coordinates i draw triangles but i want to draw the triangle with lines, so i have to match the coordenates 2x2 to create lines

Comment: @DiogoCosta - What's `vec2` is that another function you've written?

Comment: vec2 is a function in openGL to make vetor with the 2 coordinates in 1 index

Comment: the types vec2, vec3, and vec4 represent 2D, 3D, and 4D floating-point vectors

Comment: Quickly... I guess by "for ( i = 0; i < vertices.length / 3; i = +3)" you mean actually "for ( i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3)"

Comment: exactly but lines continue empty i dont know why

Comment: I'm not sure the code does what you want, but at least it gives result, check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vmzc0vms/ (just uncomment the "alert" line at the end and run it => lines are not empty). So if you really get empty lines, most probably it's due to the input data you're providing (vertices and/or lineMode). Maybe if you show us more code we could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your function makes a lot of sense, as it seems to be taking an array of values and then pushing that into another array (which seems identical) and then returning it.

Whatever you're trying to achieve the problems will probably be related to either :

1. `if (lineMode == true) {}` - lineMode doesn't evaluate to `true` and so `lines` will never be returned.
2. `vec2` isn't defined and so the function call fails whenever you pass `vertices`

Here's a live sample of testing your code : -

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qabnx4ph/29/)

By using your code in the example, the same array is alerted to the screen. What is your expected output?

Comment: to define a triangle in openGL i need 3 points, in this case the vertices array. but in my other case i have to be 6 points, because i need 2 points to define each side of the triangle t

Comment: when i call var lines=triangulosParaLinhas(vertices), the result return array from the function triangulosParaLinhas(vertices) dont save in lines?

Comment: @DiogoCosta - Ok well whatever the purpose of your function, the only reason that `lines` wouldn't return the value of the function call would be if `lineMode` is false and therefore your code wouldn't fall into the `if statement`